# Example of Hilbert space non isomorphic to $L2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm looking for an example of a Hilbert space that can't be seen as the countable direct sum of $L^{2}(X,\mu)$ spaces nor subespaces of $L^{2}(X,\mu)$. Some idea to start? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Every Hilbert space is isometric to $\ell^2(A)$ for some set $A$. Just pick an orthonormal basis.

Comment: What is dimension of $L^2$ generally? If  it has infinite dimension, ...

Comment: The typical assignment of dimension for a Hilbert space is through the cardinality of a complete orthonormal basis. If a Hilbert space has orthonormal bases $\mathscr{B}_1$ and $\mathscr{B}_2$, then $|\mathscr{B}_1| = |\mathscr{B}_2|$. A Hilbert space can have any cardinality. Every Hilbert space may be viewed as $L^2(\mathscr{B},\nu)$ where $\nu$ is counting measure and $\mathscr{B}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: One question: Doesn't the Hilbert space need to be separable to have an orthonormal basis?

Comment: @D1X No.  A Hilbert space is separable exactly when its orthonormal basis is countable.